# Grab specific table with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I want to grab the information from the table that I have highlighted in the picture below. 
[image: Source]

I am able to this if I use BeautifulSoup 3 then I can grab the table and then extract information with it, but not if I use BeautifulSoup 4. The code I have working for BS3 is:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs (open("information.html"))

table = soup.find("table", {"color":"#000000"})
print table
```

And when I print table it will print what is in that table (it's also the only table with a colour of #000000).

For BS4 I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs (open("information.html"))

table = soup.find("table", {"color":"#000000"})
print table
```

But all that is printed is either `None` or `[]`. I tired changing find to find_all and findAll, but that didn't help. I also tried adding `attrs=` before the {} (I saw it suggested on another SO question).
If I do the soup.find in the first table with `table = soup.find("table", {"width":"#000000"})` The first table is returned. How can I get it to grab the table that I want?

Comment: this should work well of course, check your environment again

Comment: I just tried this in a linux environment and it worked and tried the **same** code on windows and it didn't work...